# How to analyze factorial design with additional one control group?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I saw the term "incomplete factorial design " [here](https://conjointly.com/kb/factorial-design-variations/)

And basically in the simplest case, it is a 2x2 factorial design with an additional no-treatment control group.

I'm not sure about which test can be applied to this situation.

I considered 2-Way ANOVA, however, the no treatment group is not included in neither two factor,
how can I do the comparison ?
I would like to compare both no treatment, treatment method1 & treatment method2.

[incomplete factorial design example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcW3e.png)

Comment: This is better suited to the stats site.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry, I thought statistic is a sub-domain of mathematics. I did post this at Cross Valid, but no one reply for this. Is anything unclear?